# object not being updated after form_valid

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a `Question` and a `Reply`.

When a `Reply` is created, I want to set the related `Question`'s attribute to `new_replies = True`. This switch should happen after creating a `Reply` object using a generic CreateView / a form.

I can get the object to update immediately after submitting the form, but refreshing the page makes the update go away. I think this is because the update is not being saved to the database

`Models.py`

```
class Reply(models.Model):
    parent_question = models.ForeignKey(Question, null=True) 

class Question(models.Model):
    new_replies = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

`Views.py`

```
class ReplyCreate(CreateView):
"""
creates a comment object
"""
model = Reply #specify which model can be created here
fields = ['content', ] # which fields can be openly editted

...

def form_valid(self, form):
    """
    add associate blog and author to form.
    """
    #this is setting the author of the form
    form.instance.author = self.request.user.useredus

    #associate comment with Question based on passed
    parent_question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk= self.kwargs['pk'])
    form.instance.parent_question = parent_question

    response = super(ReplyCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    # PROBLEM: not being saved to dB?
    parent_question.new_replies = True  # inform the question there are new replies
    parent_question.save()

    return response

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('edus:question_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk'], })
```

Comment: each question has two users? This should be saved in the questions model.  Then you call this attribute and in the form validation you can update the second user profile since you know who the second user is.

Comment: No, a question will only have one user.